# How to build a QImage from known pixel values

Tags: c++, image, qt

I know the height and width, as well as each pixel value (from x,y location) that I want a QImage to be.  How can I build a QImage knowing these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply create the object (eg, `new QImage(640, 480);`) and then use [setPixel](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qimage.html#setPixel-2) to change each pixel in the image to the value you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks.  How do you set the R,G, and B components with this though?

Comment: No need to create the image on the heap, it's implicitely shared.

Answer (score 5):

The second argument to setPixel() is a 24bit RGB value in a single int you can use the [QRgb](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcolor.html#QRgb-typedef) macros to construct it or just `(red<<16) + (green << 8) + blue`

But unless it's a very small image it will take a long time to call [setPixel()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#setPixel-2).

If you have the data I would call [Qimage::bits()](http://QImage%3a%3abytesPerLine%20%28%29) to get an unsigned pointer to the QImage data and just set the R,G,B values directly for each pixel or use memcpy()